# issue with json.dumps adding extra \\ to variables

Tags: python, json, openstack

I am currently working on a python client to talk with a webservice I am developing.  Currently I am running into a issue where my webservice is expecting a very specific formated request but when I send my request thru json.dumps its adding in extra \ that causes my webservice to fail out.

Here is a example of the problem just typing some code into python:

```
>>> import json
>>> body = {}
>>> body['hosts'] = '["cso22"]'
>>> print json.dumps(body)
{"hosts": "[\"CSO22\"]"}
```

So now instead of body['hosts'] equaling '["CSO22"]' it equals '[\\"CSO22\\"]' which isn't what my webservice is expecting so it returns back http error 400. Is there a way to change this behavor so that json.dumps will return back the value i need it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `'["CSO22"]'` to create an array:

```
body = {'hosts': ["CSO22"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's supposed to be a list containing 1 element, the string `"CSO22"`, then remove the single quotes.

```
>>> body = {'hosts': ["CSO22"]}
>>> print json.dumps(body)
{"hosts": ["CSO22"]}
```